# Finding $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}$ with squeeze theorem

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I find:

$$ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x} $$

Using the squeeze theorem.  Particularly, how would I arrive at its bounding functions?

If possible, please try not to use derivatives.

Comment: Is there any particular reason on using squeeze theorem? Multiplying $1+ \cos (x)$ in both numerator and denominator would be something more natural to do to me.

Comment: @Soarer I want to the squeeze theorem because its the requirement of the homework.

Comment: More solutions to this limit are [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/81768/43351) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/420698/43351).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a geometric squeeze:

[image]

Now we can show that:

$$ \frac{1 - \cos x}{x} \lt \sin \frac{x}{2}$$

We have $\displaystyle y = x/2$ ($\triangle ABC$ is isosceles and so $\angle CAB = \frac{\pi - x}{2}$) and hence in $\triangle BDA$, $\displaystyle \sin \frac{x}{2} = \frac{AD}{AB} \gt \frac{AD}{x}$, as $\displaystyle x$ is the length of the arc $\displaystyle AB$.

Comment: Did you draw this image?  If so, how did you do it?

Comment: @DJC: Yes, using mspaint...

Comment: @DJC: I have updated the figure using one drawn with GeoGebra :-)

Comment: Cool. Thanks! (more letters)

Answer (score 5):

We can write $\cos(x)$ as $1 - x^2/2 + x^4/6 - \cdots$ and so near $x = 0$ we have $1 - \cos(x) < x^2/2$, and so $\frac{1 - \cos(x)}{x} < \frac{x^2}{2x} = \frac{x}{2}$. At the same time, $\cos(x) < 1$ so $\frac{1 - \cos(x)}{x} > 0$. Thus we have $\lim_{x\to0}0 \leq \lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x} \leq \lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{2}$, which by the squeeze theorem is $0$.

Comment: The correcct upper bound is $1 - cos (x) < 1 - 1 + x^2/2$ for $x$ close to 0. This can be seen by multiplying $\frac{1+\cos (x)}{1+\cos (x)}$, and bounding $1+\cos (x)$ away from 0 for $x$ close to 0.

Comment: @Soarer: Yes, I got that already.

Comment: Is there a way you could solve this without expanding cos(x) to that series?

Answer (score 3):

For any $x$ such that $0 < |x| \leq \pi/2$, 
$$
0 \le \bigg|\frac{{1 - \cos x}}{x}\bigg| = \frac{{1 - \cos |x|}}{{|x|}} = \frac{{\int_0^{|x|} {\sin t \,dt} }}{{|x|}} \le \frac{{\int_0^{|x|} {\sin |x| \, dt} }}{{|x|}} = \sin |x|.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Using that $|\sin x| \le |x|$

$$\frac{1-\cos x}{|x|}=\frac{\sin^2 x}{|x|(1+\cos x)} \le \frac{|x|}{1+\cos x}\to 0$$