# Finding $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos x}{x}$, given $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$

Tags: calculus, limits

I am working on a textbook problem. The first step is to prove that

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$

(which I did). The exercise goes on

> Use this limit *[i.e. the one above]* to find 
>   $$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos x}{x}$$.

How can this be done? I don't really see a connection between the two...

Comment: Use $\cos  \theta=1-2\sin^2(\theta/2)$

Comment: Hint: $1-\cos x=\frac{1-\cos^2 x}{1+\cos x}=\frac{\sin^2 x}{1+\cos x}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Maybe you should point that this is natural: $1-\cos(x)= 1- \sqrt{1-\sin^2(x)}$ and you rationalize....

Comment: @N.S.: A good comment for the OP to consider! I was just giving a hint on how to start.

Comment: More solutions to this limit are [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/420698/43351) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/36299/43351).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using half-angle formula, we have $1-\cos x = 2\sin^2\frac x2$ so
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x} = 2\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2\frac x2}{x} = \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin\frac x2}{x/2}\cdot\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\sin\frac x2 = 1\cdot0 = 0
$$
where we used the fact that both limits exist.

Answer (score 9):

$$
\begin{eqnarray*} 
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos{x}}{x}  
&=& \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1-\cos{x})(1+\cos x)}{x(1+\cos x)} 
\\ &=& \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos^2 x}{x(1 + \cos x)} 
\\ &=& \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x\sin^2 x}{x \cdot x(1+ \cos x)} 
\\ &=& \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} \times \frac{\sin{x}}{x}\times \frac{x}{1+\cos x} = 0 .
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}
L = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos{x}}{x} &= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin^{2}{x} + \cos^{2}{x} -\cos{x}}{x} \\ &= \lim_{x \to 0} \cos(x) \cdot \frac{\cos{x}-1}{x} + \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin^{2}{x}}{x} \\ &=-L \Rightarrow 2L =0 \Rightarrow L=0
\end{align*}

Comment: Aren't you presupposing the limit exists?

Answer (score 1):

Using L'Hopital

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos x}{x} = \lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{(1 - \cos x)'}{x'} =  \lim \limits_{x \to 0} \sin x = 0$$

Comment: That seems quite a circular argument if you take the definitions of $\sin$ and $\cos$ from the unit circle. How do you know the derivative of $\cos x$ without using what you are trying to prove?