# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}$$

Could someone help me with this trigonometric limit? I am trying to evaluate it without l'Hôpital's rule and derivation.

Comment: More solutions to this limit are [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/81768/43351) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/36299/43351).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{x}=  \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x)}{
x(1+\cos x)}=\lim_{x\to 0} \displaystyle\frac{(1-\cos^2 x)}{
x(1+\cos x)}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin^2 x}{
x(1+\cos x)}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x\sin^2 x}{
x^2(1+\cos x)}=\lim_{x\to 0} \displaystyle\frac{\sin^2 x}{
x^2}\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{1+\cos x}=1\times 0=0
$

O you simply apply L'Hopital rule and
$$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{x}=\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(1-\cos x)'}{x'}=\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{1}=0$$

Comment: or you simply apply L'h

Comment: L'HR makes a lot of trigonometric limit problems _super_ easy, although this particular limit is often introduced in calculus courses well before the Rule appears (since we generally need this limit to obtain the derivatives of sine and cosine).

Answer (score 12):

**Hint:** Multiply top and bottom by $1+\cos x$. Then use a probably known fact about $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$.

Comment: Muito obrigada!

Comment: but when i replace the x per 0?

Comment: Our expression is equal to $\frac{1}{1+\cos x}\frac{\sin x}{x}\sin x$. As $x\to 0$, the $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ part approaches $1$, and the dangling $\sin x$ part approaches $0$, so the product approaches $0$.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative method, $\cos x=1+ O(x^2)$. Then $$O(x^2)/x= O(x)$$

---

*Edit*: The notation $f(x)=O(g(x))$ means that $f(x)/g(x)$ is bounded by a constant (in the limit). Put simply, *this means $f$ is no bigger than $g$ in the limit*.

This answer basically relies on the Taylor expansion of the numerator. Typically this is the quickest way to get to the answer with these sorts of limits.

For example, l'Hôpital's rule is seen to be because if $f(0)=g(0)=0$ for functions which can be approximated to some order by a Taylor series then $f(x)/g(x)= (x f'(0)+O(x^2))/(xg'(0)+O(x^2))$ and one can cancel the $x$s.

Comment: I would *suspect* (though I don't know for a fact) that anybody asking this type of question would be unfamiliar with $O$-notation - and, assuming this comes from a classroom context, they are probably not allowed these sorts of arguments in any case.

Comment: I've added a quick definition. However, I see the point in answering this type of question to be just providing other ways (possibly more general) to look at the problem. Most mathematicians, confronted with this, do not think "Aha, let us do a clever manipulation to relate it to some standard limit", they think "Errr, that's trivial by Taylor expansion". I see no harm on introducing the idea.

Comment: Oh, don't get me wrong.  I certainly wasn't saying there was any harm.  Please, take the comment as coming from a mathematician who has seen WAY too many students try to reach into bags of tricks that they don't understand!

Comment: Fair enough, I suppose! I'm mainly reacting to the "Find a fancy way to do it" school of answer, which is fine, but is worth balancing out. (:

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}$$
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-(1-2\sin^2 \dfrac x2)}{x}$$
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2\sin^2\dfrac x2}{x}$$
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x\sin^2\dfrac x2}{4\left(\dfrac x2\right)^2}$$
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{2}\cdot \lim_{x\to0}\left(\dfrac{\sin \dfrac x2}{\dfrac x2}\right)^2$$
$$0\cdot 1$$
$$0$$

Answer (score 3):

Using the definition of derivative: $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}= - \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos(x)-\cos(0)}{x-0}=- \cos'(0)=-\sin(0)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Write 
$$\frac{1-\cos x}{x} = \frac{\cos 0 -\cos x }{x} = \frac{-2\sin\left( {0 + x \over 2}\right) \sin\left({0 -x \over 2}\right)}{x} = \frac{\sin^2(x/2)}{x/2}$$
and then
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2(x/2)}{x/2} =  \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x/2)}{x/2}\cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\sin (x/2) .
$$

Answer (score 1):

There is also a fairly direct method based on trig identities and the limit $ \ \lim_{\theta \rightarrow 0} \ \tan \frac{\theta}{2} \ = \ 0 , $ which I discuss in the first half of my post [here](http://recklessreckoner.blogspot.com/2013/03/the-small-angle-approximation-ii-little.html).

[In brief,

$$ \lim_{\theta \rightarrow 0} \ \tan \frac{\theta}{2} \ = \ 0 \ = \ \lim_{\theta \rightarrow 0} \ \frac{1 - \cos \theta}{\sin \theta}  \ = \ \lim_{\theta \rightarrow 0} \ \frac{1 - \cos \theta}{\theta}  \ \cdot \ \frac{\theta}{\sin \theta} $$

$$= \ \lim_{\theta \rightarrow 0} \ \frac{1 - \cos \theta}{\theta}  \ \cdot \ \frac{1}{\lim_{\theta \rightarrow 0} \ \frac{\sin \theta}{\theta} } \ = \ \lim_{\theta \rightarrow 0} \ \frac{1 - \cos \theta}{\theta}  \ \cdot \ \frac{1}{1} \ \Rightarrow  \ \lim_{\theta \rightarrow 0} \ \frac{1 - \cos \theta}{\theta} \ = \ 0 \ . ] $$