# Differentiability of a function satisfying a condition on a bounded interval

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let  $\displaystyle f(x)$ satisfies the condition $|f(x)|\leq 1-\cos x$ on the interval $-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Prove that $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and find $f^\prime(0)$.

My idea:

$\lim_{x\to 0} |\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}|\leq \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{|f(x)|+|f(0)|}{x}\leq \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x }{x}\leq \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2 }{x}$

but i m stack in here

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you written out the definition of $f'(0)$ in terms of a limit?

Comment: I wrote but i still cant have any idea how can i proceed in the proof.

Comment: Why don't you edit your question to describe what you've done so far? Can you tell us the value of $f(0)$?

Comment: Write down the definition of the derivative of $\cos$ in $0$. (Why) does that help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition forces $f(0)=0$. Now,
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \frac{f(x)}{x},
$$
and 
$$
\left| \frac{f(x)}{x} \right| \leq \frac{1-\cos x}{|x|}.
$$
Letting $x \to 0$, what do you get?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are stuck because you are not familiar with the fact that
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x }{x}=0.$$

You can find the proof here:
[Evaluating $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420698/evaluating-lim-x-to0-frac1-cosxx?lq=1)