# $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x\cos(x)} $ without L'hopital

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

Please help me to solve this limit without using *L'Hôpital's rule*. I don't know what other method can't be used to solve this limit.

### $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x\cos(x)}  $$

Comment: A start: Multiply top and bottom by $1+\cos x$.

Comment: Usually $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}x = 0$ is proven at the same time as $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}x = 1$ is, in the development of the derivatives of $\sin$ and $\cos$. Since $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac 1{\cos x} = 1$ by continuity, your limit is $0\cdot 1 = 0$.

Comment: The answers given here might be useful, too: [Evaluating $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/420698)

Answer (score 10):

**HINT:**

$$\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x\cos(x)}=\frac{2\sin^2(x/2)}{x\cos(x)} \tag 1$$

---

**SPOILER ALERT:** Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution

> Using $(1)$ we have  $$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x\cos(x)}&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2\sin^2(x/2)}{x\cos(x)}\\\\&=\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x/2)}{x/2}\right)\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x/2)}{\cos(x)}\right)\\\\&=(1)(0)\\\\&=0\end{align}$$

Comment: Nice! As usual, I assumed the OP knows Taylor Series lol. This is more grounded, may fit better with his knowledge.

Comment: @1over137 Thank you very much.  Very appreciative!  And you are probably correct.  -Mark

Comment: +1 I found this answer very useful, not sure how OP feels.

Comment: @johnjoy pleased to hear!  And much appreciative of the comment. -Mark

Comment: Don't you need l'hopitals for $/frac{sin(x)}{x}$

Comment: Oh wait, is that where you used Taylor series for sine?

Comment: @mikevandernaald Recall from elementary geometry that $x\cos(x)\le \sin(x)\le x$.  Then, divide by $x$ and apply the squeeze theorem to arrive at the limit in question. L'hospital's Rule is not needed here.  -Mark

Comment: @mikevandernaald See the details of a geometric proof here http://math.stackexchange.com/a/922970/140156

Comment: @mikevandernaald Using LH to compute the limit of $\sin x/x$ at $0$ is a fallacy since LH requires the value of the derivative of the sine at $0$ which *by definition* is the limit of $(\sin x-0)/(x-0)=\sin x/x$.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is a follow-up to André Nicolas' and Paul Sinclair's comments

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x\cos x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x\cos x}\cdot\frac{1+\cos x}{1+\cos x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos^2 x}{x\cos x(1+\cos x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x\cos x(1+\cos x)}$$

Note that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, that $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin x=0$, that $\lim_{x\to 0}\cos x=1$, and  that $\lim_{x\to 0}(1+\cos x)=2$ giving the final result
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x\cos x}=0$$

Answer (score 3):

Use Taylor series

$$\cos(x) \approx 1 - \frac{x^2}{2}$$ thence

$$\frac{1 - \cos(x)}{x\cos(x)} = \frac{1 - \left(1 - \frac{x^2}{2}\right)}{x\cdot\left(1 - \frac{x^2}{2}\right)} = \frac{x^2}{2x - x^3} = \frac{x^2}{x^2\left(\frac{2}{x} - x\right)} = \frac{1}{\frac{2}{x}} = \frac{x}{2}$$

And since $x\to 0$ the limit is

$$\boxed{0}$$

Comment: +1 Although there are those on this site who attach some equivalence with LHR and Taylor series.

Comment: @Dr.MV Super thank you! Maybe Taylor Series can be inappropriate sometimes, but I thought in that case it held ^^

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  I actually prefer asymptotics over LHR for many situations.

Answer (score 3):

Note that 
$
  \displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{1-\cos x}{x}
  =-\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\cos x-\cos 0}{x - 0}
  =-\left.\cos'x\right|_{x=0}
  = \sin 0 = 0
$

So 
$ \displaystyle
  \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x\cos(x)}
  = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x} \cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1}{\cos(x)}
  = 0 \cdot 1 = 0
$

Comment: But how do you prove $cos'(x) = - sin(x)$?

Comment: @EugenCovaci - If you're at the point where you know what L'Hôpital's rule is, you should already know.

Comment: The question is: how do you prove $cos'(x) = - sin(x)$ without L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: @EugenCovaci - where does it say that?

Comment: "Please help me to solve this limit without using L'Hôpital's rule" I suppose this means avoinding direct or indirect use of  L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: @EugenCovaci - I didn't use L'Hôpital's rule, I used the definition of the derivative of the cosine function.

Comment: You used $cos'(0) = - sin(0)$.

Comment: @eugencovaci Recall from elementary geometry that $x\cos(x)\le \sin(x)\le x$.  Divide by $x$ and apply the squeeze theorem to arrive at the limit in question.  No L'Hospital's Rule and no differential calculus was used.

Comment: @Dr. MV I know, but this should be in the prove, don't you think?

Comment: @eugencovaci I don't believe that we need to start with a result from elementary geometry. It does beg the question as to appropriate assumptions on a fair starting point.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{1-\cos x}{x\cos x} = \frac{2 \sin^2 (x/2)}{x \cos x}= \frac{\sin (x/2)}{x/2} \frac{\sin (x/2)}{\cos x}$
The limit is $0$.

Comment: Yes! And what does this mean?

Comment: It means that you write faster than me. Nothing els, sir.

Answer (score 0):

frist :

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

now :

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{x\cos x}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}.\frac{x^2}{x\cos x}\\=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}.\frac{x}{\cos x}=?$$

since:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{\cos x}=0$$

so :

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}.\frac{x}{\cos x}=(\frac{1}{2})(0)=0$$