# Finding value of the limit by using the definition of derivative.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

How to find the value of this limit by using the definition of derivative  :

$$ \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin (x^{2}+h)-\sin x^{2}}{h} $$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\sin{\left((x+h)^{2}\right)}$?

Comment: $f'(a) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$. From this you can get $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin (x^{2}+h)-\sin x^{2}}{h} = \sin' x^2 = \cos x^2$.

Comment: @copper.hat Won't it become $2x\cos{(x^2)}$?

Comment: @ladaghini: No; it would have if it was $\sin((x+h)^2)$, though. Notice the subtle difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First substitute $y=x^2$, so that you have

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin(y+h) - \sin y}{h}$$

Does this look familiar? It's the definition of the derivative of $\sin$ evaluated at the point $y$. Now substitute back.

**Edit:** Didn't see this had been answered by copper.hat in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(x^2+h)-\sin x^2} h$$
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(x^2)\cos(h)+\sin(h)\cos(x^2)-\sin x^2} h$$
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(x^2)(\cos(h)-1)} h +\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(h)\cos(x^2)} h$$

You can prove geometrically ([see here, for example](http://www.ies.co.jp/math/java/calc/LimSinX/LimSinX.html)) that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin h} h=1$, and that  $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1-\cos h} h=0$ ([see this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36299/finding-the-limit-of-1-cosx-x-as-x-to-0-with-squeeze-theorem)), which gives the appropriate limit.