# Find $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos x - 1}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to find the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos x - 1}{x}$$

I tried to use squeeze theorem but it's not making much sense. I did the following:

$$\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos x - 1}{x} \\
-1 \le &\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (\cos x)(x^{-1}) \le 1 \\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} -x^{-1} \le &\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \cos x \le \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x^{-1} \quad \text{*}
\end{align}$$

The last line is where I'm confused. I don't think I'm doing squeeze theorem correctly. I'm guessing you have to manipulate $\cos x - 1$ somehow. Please provide some hints.

Thanks a bunch!

P.S You cannot use L'Hopital.

Comment: Hint: $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos(x) - 1}{x}  = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos(x) - \cos(0)}{x - 0}.$$

Comment: Multiply top and bottom by $\cos x+1$.

Comment: Why can't we use L'Hospital? (Not that I'd want to.) You can use a Taylor approximation of the cosine.

Comment: I'm aware of both L'Hospital and Taylor aprrox but we haven't covered it in class so I can't really use that.

Comment: Both L'Hospital and Taylor approximations are circular.

Comment: The tag ([tag:limit-theorems]) is intended for questions about limit theorems in probability theory and not for questions about determining limits of sequences or functions, see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/limit-theorems/info) and the tag-excerpt. (The tag-excerpt is also shown when you are adding a tag to a question.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the limit of $(1-\cos(x))/x$ as $x\to 0$ with squeeze theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36299/finding-the-limit-of-1-cosx-x-as-x-to-0-with-squeeze-theorem)

Comment: @JLA There are [proofs for the derivative of cosine](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Cosine_Function) not relying on either the limit or defining cosine by its Maclaurin series, though.

Comment: @Divide1918 I don't see how that impacts my comment though.

Comment: @JLA If you use a proof for derivative of cosine not relying on the limit, how is using the derivative of cosine (e.g. via L'Hopital's rule) to solve the limit circular?

Comment: @Divide1918 The question is asking to find the derivative of $\cos{x}$ at $0,$ using Hopital's rule requires prior knowledge of what the derivative is.

Comment: @JLA I believe you ought to read my first reply again. I reckon you didn’t quite comprehend it.

Comment: @Divide1918 Does your definition of the derivative also not involve a limit? If not, then you're right I don't understand what your argument is. Perhaps you should just write it out.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint 1:* $$\cos x -1 = -2\sin^2 \dfrac{x}2$$
*Hint 2:* $$\dfrac{\cos x - 1}{x} = \dfrac{(\cos x - 1)(\cos x + 1)}{x(\cos x + 1)} = -\dfrac{\sin^2 x}{x^2} \dfrac{x}{1+\cos x}.$$

Comment: I tried the second method prior to squeeze but it didn't work. I suspect, I didn't simplify properly. Once you expand the top, you get $\sin^2x - 1$ then do you convert $\sin^2x$ into something or do you convert the $1$ into something?

Comment: We get $\cos^2 x-1 = -\sin^2 x$, not $\sin^2 x -1$.

Comment: Sorry, does the $\frac{-\sin^2x}{x^2}$ become  $\frac{x}{1+\cos x}$ or is it all one thing being multiplied?

Comment: They are being multiplied. I wrote it in this form because we know that $\dfrac{\sin x}{x} \to 1$, as $x \to 0$.

Comment: So in essence what is happening is that the $\sin x^2x$ fraction is going to $-1$ while the other is going $0$ therefore, the limit is zero right?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11351/discussion-between-gekkostate-and-njguliyev)

Answer (score 2):

If you know that $\sin \theta \lt \theta$ when $\theta\gt0$, then you can argue that

$$0\lt\left| {1-\cos x\over x}\right|\lt\left|{1-\cos^2x\over x}\right|=\left|{\sin^2x\over x}\right|\lt \left|\sin x\right|$$

at which point the Squeeze Theorem takes over.  If you need to prove the inequality $\sin\theta\lt\theta$, note that ${1\over2}\sin\theta$ (for small $\theta$, at least) is the area of the triangle inside the unit circle with vertices at the origin, $(1,0)$, and $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$, whereas ${1\over2}\theta$ is the area of the sector containing the triangle. (Alternatively, note that $\sin\theta$, being the vertical distance from $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ to the $x$-axis, is less than the distance from $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ to $(1,0)$, which is less than the arc length connecting those two points, namely $\theta$.)

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$

By Mean Value Theorem:
$$
\verts{\cos\pars{x} - 1 \over x} = \verts{\sin\pars{\xi}}
\quad\mbox{where}\quad
\left\vert%
\begin{array}{lcl}
\quad 0 < \xi < x & \mbox{if} & x > 0
\\
\mbox{or}&&
\\
\quad x < \xi < 0 & \mbox{if} & x < 0
\end{array}\right.
$$

Now, use 'Sandwich Theorem'.

Comment: Sadly, I don't know Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: $\large\tt \mbox{Mean Value Theorem}\ --->\quad$ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Comment: It's been a long time since I took calculus, but don't the differentiation formulas for sine and cosine come **after** the limits of $\frac{\sin x}x$ and $\frac{1-\cos x}x$ as $x\to0$?

Comment: That's $0$k. Any way it's time to refresh it. Anybody over here is refreshing somehow every day. Don't worry about.

Comment: This answer is circular, using the derivative of cosine.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = \cos(x)$, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos x - 1}{x} = f'(0) = -\sin(0) = 0$

Comment: The limit the OP asked about is used to prove the differentiation formula for $\cos x$. It would be circular to use the derivative of $\cos x$ to prove the limit.

Comment: @bof There are [proofs for the derivative of cosine](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Cosine_Function) not relying on either the limit or defining cosine by its Maclaurin series, though.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative

$$\frac{\cos x - 1}{x}=\frac {\sin x}x\frac{\cos x - 1}{\sin x}$$

with $\frac {\sin x}x\to 1 $ and by tangent half-angle or double angle identities
$$\frac{\cos x - 1}{\sin x}=-\tan \frac x 2 \to 0$$

Answer (score -1):

It is sufficient to use the asymptotic development of $\cos x$ around $0$, namely

$$\cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + o(x^3).$$

Comment: MacLaurin/Taylor series are not available, because this limit is used to derive them -- circularity lurks.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. From the a.d. we obtain cos x-1 = -x^2/2 + o(x^3). If we divide by x, for x small and non-zero, then we obtain (cos x-1)/x = -x/2 + o(x^2). Now letting x go tO 0 we obtain the limit 0.

Comment: I made a typing error: go to 0.

Comment: @Lord_Farin There are [proofs for the derivative of cosine](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Cosine_Function) not relying on either the limit or defining cosine by its Maclaurin series. And of course, if you define cosine by its Maclaurin series, using it wouldn’t be circular.