# can you multiply a limit that doesn't exist times a limit that is equal to zero?

Tags: calculus

$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x \ -  \ \sin x \cos x}{x^2\cos x}$$

I graphed it and got zero, and I also tried to solve it algebraically by first factoring out $\dfrac{\sin x}{x} $so that it equals one and you're left with $\dfrac{1-\cos x}{x\cos x}$.  I then separated this into two fractions, $\dfrac{1}{x\cos x}-\dfrac{\cos x}{x\cos x}$ canceled the $\cos x $ to get $\dfrac{1}{x \cos x}- \dfrac 1x$, then factored out $\dfrac1x$ to get $\lim \dfrac1x \times \lim  \dfrac 1{\cos x} - 1$, which is zero.

So it basically came down to $\lim \dfrac{\sin x}{x}\times \lim \dfrac 1x \times \lim 0$   I thought that even though you get 1, doesn't exist, and zero, respectively, you could just assume the limit was zero since anything times zero is zero.  Additionally, I thought this answer was right because when I graphed the function, the limit was indeed zero.

any help would be greatly appreciated!  thanks!

Comment: It's sinx-cosxsinx.  sorry, clicked approve edits but didn't realize the problem changed.

Comment: Like that now?  (after a refreshing editing break...) There is also a known limit for $ \ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \ \frac{1 \ - \ \cos x}{x} \ $ .

Comment: yes, thank you very much!

Comment: You cannot "split" a limit (except if all the limits you write exist)! For example, $\lim_{x\to  0} x/x = 1$ but $1/x$ has no limit in $0$.

Comment: @anderstood  It's OK for the problem as has been resolved (there was a bit of "dueling editors" going on here for a little while...).

Comment: A safe way to find the limit is to use a Taylor expansion ($\sin(x)=x+o(x^2)$ in the neighbourhood of $0$ and $\cos(x)=1-x^2/2+o(x^3)$)

Comment: @RecklessReckoner The answer has not been accepted (yet), there is no need for the unicity of an answer, and more importantly the answer does not underline the _big_ mistake of the OP.

Comment: @anderstood thanks :) however, is there any simpler way to show how you get the answer?  This is actually for test corrections for calc A, and we're just on the second chapter and I think my teacher expects us to prove the problem based on what we've learned.

Comment: @Melissa: ADG's answer is fine, and you probably have the knowledge to understand it. If it suits you, accept it. And remember that you can only split limits into a product of limits which exist! :)

Comment: @anderstood I was addressing a different issue since the problem statement kept being altered in multiple edits, but it's no matter now.

Comment: Who does allow you to separate A and B in $\lim_{x\to 0}{(A\times B)}??$

Comment: @anderstood thank you so much!  I get it now :)

Comment: @RecklessReckoner thanks so much!  :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better try splitting it into finite products!
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x-\cos x\sin x}{x^2\cos x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\underbrace{\frac{\sin x}{x}}_{1}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{1-\cos x}{x}}_{0}\cdot\underbrace{\frac1{\cos x}}_{1}=1\cdot0\cdot1=0$$

Comment: how do you know the limit of 1-cosx/x is zero?

Comment: @Melissa By knowing that the limit of $\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2/2}$ equals $1$, which follows from the limit of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ being $1$, by using that $\cos(0)=1$, and adding the two cosines.

Comment: @Melissa see these links: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/36299), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/81768), [3](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/420698), [4](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/552016)

Comment: ADG and @Pp.. thank you guys so much for your help! :) It's very much appreciated!

Comment: @Melissa: If this answer helped you, accept it! That is the way to show appreciation to the best answer (and this is the *only* answer right now). When you get enough reputation you can vote up all answers that help.